# C++ on Solaris: How to cope with "Formal argument" wrongly passed error?

Tags: c++, solaris, z3, solaris-studio

I am trying to compile the SMT solver Z3 (Version 4.5.0) from Microsoft Research on a Solaris 10 (Sparc) with Solaris Studio 12.3 (and this is due to constraints that I cannot change, so please do not hint to gcc/g++).

I already had to make some (more or less trivial) code changes in order to come to the error I am opposed with now:

```
"../src/util/map.h", line 54: Error: Formal argument p of type const std::pair<expr*, int>& in call to pair_hash<obj_ptr_hash<expr>, int_hash>::operator()(const std::pair<expr*, int>&) const is being passed const std::pair<expr*, bool>.
"../src/util/hashtable.h", line 155:     Where: While instantiating "table2map<default_map_entry<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>, pair_hash<obj_ptr_hash<expr>, int_hash>, default_eq<std::pair<expr*, bool>>>::entry_hash_proc::operator()(const _key_data<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>&) const".
"../src/util/hashtable.h", line 155:     Where: Instantiated from core_hashtable<default_map_entry<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>, table2map<default_map_entry<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>, pair_hash<obj_ptr_hash<expr>, int_hash>, default_eq<std::pair<expr*, bool>>>::entry_hash_proc, table2map<default_map_entry<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>, pair_hash<obj_ptr_hash<expr>, int_hash>, default_eq<std::pair<expr*, bool>>>::entry_eq_proc>::get_hash(const _key_data<std::pair<expr*, bool>, bool>&) const.
"../src/util/hashtable.h", line 350:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Error(s) and 33 Warning(s) detected.
*** Error code 2
The following command caused the error:
CC -D_MP_INTERNAL -DNDEBUG -D_EXTERNAL_RELEASE  -xldscope=hidden -c -xarch=sse2 -xvector=simd -D_NO_OMP_ -D _EXTERNAL_RELEASE -xO3 -xregs=frameptr -D_SUNOS_ -KPIC -xalias_level=any -features=zla -I../src/ast/rewriter/bit_blaster -I../src/ast/rewriter -I../src/ast -I../src/util -I../src/math/polynomial -I../src/math/automata -I../src/ast/simplifier -I../src/ast/macros -I../src/ast/normal_forms -I../src/cmd_context -I../src/solver -I../src/model -I../src/tactic -I../src/interp -I../src/smt/proto_model -I../src/smt/params -I../src/ast/pattern -I../src/parsers/smt2 -I../src/parsers/util -I../src/ast/substitution -I../src/math/grobner -I../src/math/euclid -I../src/math/simplex -I../src/ast/proof_checker -I../src/ast/fpa -osmt/smt_quick_checker.o ../src/smt/smt_quick_checker.cpp
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `smt/smt_quick_checker.o'
bash-3.2$
```

The code causing the error can be found [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/z3-4.5.0/src/util/map.h) at line 54.

I already poked around with a cast to `std::pair<expr*, int>`, but as this is code used with different types, this lead to a similar error with `unsigned`.

Can anybody help me with this error?

Comment: Which version of Solaris Studio 12?  I think 12.6 beta is available...

Comment: It's Solaris Studio 12.3 using cc and CC 5.12.

Comment: Can you please specify how to find line 54 given an Android smartphone?

Comment: Load the classic version of github.

Comment: @JohnSmith Assuming it's a compiler bug, can you update Solaris Studio?

Comment: @Andrew I don't think so. Are you sure that it is a compiler bug?

Comment: @JohnSmith No, I'm not sure it's a bug, but the fact that GCC apparently accepts the code probably means one of the two compilers has a bug, and it's a coin toss as to which one.  To get a definitive answer, you should probably post a question on the Oracle Solaris Studio compiler forum:  https://community.oracle.com/community/server_&_storage_systems/application_development_in_c__c++__and_fortran/developer_studio_c_c++_fortran_compilers  The first response you get will almost certainly be to upgrade.

Comment: I can't tell from the compiler output what the caller is. In case it maintains a map to integers or Booleans. If there are some fixes we can integrate into the master branch feel free to open a GitHub issue or pull request.

Comment: It appears you created a map who's HashProc expects a `const std::pair<expr*, int>&)`, and are using it in a map of `expr*` to `bool`.